# How to customize on window close message in IE?

Tags: javascript

on window close we get below message"Are you sure you want to navigate away from this page?". is there any way to replace this message with my own message?

Please help me.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The message is the return value of `onbeforeunload` event handler:

```
window.onbeforeunload = function() {
    return 'Custom message';
};
```

Unfortunately, such custom messages aren't supported in newer versions of Firefox.

Answer (score 1):

You could try subscribing for the [onbeforeunload](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/window.onbeforeunload) event and return the message:

```
window.onbeforeunload = function (e) {
  e = e || window.event;

  // For IE and Firefox prior to version 4
  if (e) {
    e.returnValue = 'some custom message';
  }

  // For Safari
  return 'some custom message';
};
```